# Block emails from specific sender only in Mac OS mail program

Tags: mail.app, email

I have an email account registered on my Macbook and on two more devices. Is it possible to block / not download all emails from a specific sender just on my device but not touch the server email account settings, so the sender can still send to the two other devices?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to set a rule so that if the sender is this than archive message, I wouldn't recommend deleting the message as (depending on your mail server's settings) it may delete the message also on your other devices.

Hope this helps,

Tiferrei

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. AFAIK, the sender would be blocked on all your Apple products or none at all.

Comment: That's exactly my problem :(